# How can I highlight regions of interest in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm wondering if it's possible to highlight important regions of a Matplotlib imshow plot like this: [image]

I tried using the contour function but it doesn't work with the data I have. I essentially want to highlight the bounds of a region which has values higher than a specified threshold as done in the image.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually this is done via `ax.contour(..., levels=[threshold])`

Comment: When you say using `contour` doesn’t work for your data, it would help to explain in what way it’s going wrong.

Comment: Thank you! ax.contour does in fact work! I just wasn't aware of the levels parameter as I thought it represented the specific location of the contour, not a logical parameter which determines it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ax.contour(data, levels=[threshold])`

Here is an example including a mark on the colorbar indicating the threshold.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import numpy as np

# create some dummy data
np.random.seed(20240211)
data = gaussian_filter(np.random.rand(50, 60), sigma=5) * 80 - 30

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.imshow(data, cmap='turbo', aspect='auto')
threshold = 11
ax.contour(data, levels=[threshold], colors='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax)
cbar.ax.axhline(threshold, color='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing a threshold on an image]